# Why are rare decays a good probe for New Physics?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, beyond-the-standard-model

It is often said that decays that are suppressed by the SM are an *excellent probe for searches* for New Physics. Why is that the case?

I understand that if a process is forbidden by the SM, such as Lepton Flavour Violation for instance, then evidence for such a process would be a clear sign of NP. How does the study of rare decays provide hints of NP however? And how do indirect searches involving precision measurements of observables in rare decays provide further evidence for physics beyond the standard model?

Comment: what do you mean by "sparce" observation? usually limits are given taking into account measurement errors and theoretical uncertainties., if the effect is not statistically significant.

Comment: Background? Looking for minuscule NP in an Old Physics  crowd is harder than looking for it in an inaccessible cave keeping most of the crowd out.

Comment: I think the emphasis on rare decays is because common decay modes have already been validated against the SM, often with high degrees of precision. Once you have carefully searched under all the lamp posts, the next step is to fell around in the dark.

Comment: @annav I don't mean anything particular. I guess another way to put my question is why deviations from SM predictions in rare decays are a better hint for NP compared to deviations fro, predictions in non-suppressed decays.

Comment: The comment by Zachos answers this.

Comment: @CosmasZachos I have a good understanding of Physics up to the level of an undergraduate degree.